# TypeError: RoaringBitmap32::add - 32 bit unsigned integer expected - Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm using [roaring bitmaps](https://github.com/SalvatorePreviti/roaring-node) to store list of ip address.

```
  const RoaringBitmap32 = require('roaring/RoaringBitmap32');
  const bitmap2 = new RoaringBitmap32([]);
  bitmap2.add("153.171.110.82");
  console.log('bitmap2.toArray():', bitmap2.toArray());
```

When I run the above program I get the below error -

```
/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/contango/scripts/rr_bitmaps_demo.js:3
bitmap2.add("153.171.110.82");
        ^

TypeError: RoaringBitmap32::add - 32 bit unsigned integer expected
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/contango/scripts/rr_bitmaps_demo.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Is there any way I can workaround on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to convert your IP to a 32bit integer as the error suggests.
IPv4 consists of 4 blocks, each block is 8 bits, so it is 32 bits in summary.

You can write your own converting function, I believe this shouldn't be too hard but if it's problematic for you then there should be some npm packages you can use. For example, I found [this one](https://github.com/joshuamarquez/node-ip-to-int)